Upgrade to 4.4 - Ajax error / 90.2% completed
I am having a terrible time upgrading from 3.10.12 to 4.4 as well and received the same Ajax error / 90.2% completed, and then a bricked site that displays no content and has no admin login.
I suspect I have an old template (3rd party, purchased from Crosstec), but it's not clear to me how to fix that.
I suspect my extensions also need to be updated, but it doesn't seem like Joomla knows where to find them. The Update tab on the Extensions page says "There are no updates available at the moment."
I have fixed the bricked site using Akeeba backup / drop databases a few times.
I have used Akeeba magic eraser, I have admin tools installed. But it seems like I have templates and extensions that need to be updated but I am not finding any luck on how to do that.
Server is running php 7.3.33. I have cPanel and Database access. Any advice you could give would be awesome.

Based on completing about 50 Joomla 3 to Joomla 4 migrations so far, I recommend the following:

In Extension Manager, sort extensions by ID by clicking on "ID" at the top right hand corner of the page so you can see all the installed third party extensions which will usually start at ID = 10000.

Before migrating to Joomla 4, remove all third party extensions that are not compatible with Joomla 4, upgrade the remaining third party extensions to the latest versions, set Protostar as the default template and then disable all third party extensions.

Not all extensions use the Joomla update system so you will need to check on third party extension developer websites to ensure you have the latest versions and to double check on Joomla 4 compatibility.

Once the migration is complete, install the latest Joomla 4 versions of third party extensions over the existing third party extensions. Then re-enable the third party extensions (one by one if issues persist so that you can find the culprit).

Re-enable your third party template (if Joomla 4 compatible), use the default template or choose a new Joomla 4 compatible template.


Joomla 4 requires a minimum of PHP v7.2.5 so PHP v7.3.33 should be OK although I have mostly upgraded to PHP v7.4 before migrating to Joomla 4.
Other suggestions:

increase max_execution_time and memory_limit PHP variables

check www prefix (or lack of www prefix) in $live_site variable is correct in configuration.php or set $live_site variable to empty string

try using the default .htaccess file for Joomla 3.10.12



Thank you very much Neil. Your instructions worked well. At some point in this website's life, Protostar got erased, so I had to re-install that template, and the software company that created the installed third party template (Crosstec) seems to have completely closed up shop. So I've still got some work to do. But your instructions solved my upgrade issues. I'd upvote your answer but I don't have the required reputation points. Cheers!
